# Why is $\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}} u'(s) ds - u'(t_n) = \int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}}(t_{n+1}-s)u''(s) ds$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I don't understand why the last step in the following equations is true. Could someone explain this to me please? Don't think context is important here, but just in case it's from a proof of a bound on the error of the explicit Euler method. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to integrate by part (integrate 1, derive $u'$) and use the fact $\Delta t=t_{n+1}-t_n$ to write $(1+t_n/\Delta t)=t_{n+1}/\Delta_t$.